# Adobe Bridge Javascript works on Windows but not Mac

Tags: script, javascript, macos, javascript-automation, adobe-bridge

I have a bridge script here that I have been running on Adobe Bridge 2022 for Windows but when I tried to run it on an imac it did not work. I have never had issues with using photoshop scripts on both machines, but this bridge one doesn't seem to take?

---

```
function re() {
    rplcd = fle.path + '/' + decodeURI(fle.name)
    .replace(/ .+(?=\.jpg)/, '_' + bdefgh.shift())
    return File(rplcd).name != nme && rplcd
}

rnmng = new MenuElement('command', 'Batch Renaming',
'at the end of Thumbnail'), rnmng.onSelect = function() {
    fls = File(pP = app.document.presentationPath).getFiles(/\.jpg$/i), cde = ''
    while(fls.length) ((slc = (nme = (fle = fls.shift()).name).slice(0, 17)) != cde) &&
    (cde = slc, bdefgh = 'bdefgh'.split('')), (rslt = re()) && fle.rename(rslt)
}
```

Comment: What exactly does "not work"? Do you get any error messages or similar>? Have you tried splitting it to see where exactly it fails?

Comment: Hi, unfortunately there is no error message - it just does not run. Is there a way to break it up or test it within visual studio?

Comment: How do you define file.path ? What works on Windows doe snot work on a mac. Seen one script on here that checks for the system and calls the "correct" path subroutine...

Comment: @SolarMike I am actually not sure - but that could be it! I will look through the bridge documentation and see if it has a different filepath call based on operating system. The filepath in this case its determined by where I run the script - whenever I rightclick and run the script - it runs on the entire folder.